# Export-Csv does not get the array parameters from json object

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I tried exporting the json to csv  from the json object but it gives me System.Object[] for array values. Here is my json file

```
$data=@"
{
    "auditReportVersion": 2,
    "vulnerabilities": {
        "@babel/traverse": {
            "name": "@babel/traverse",
            "severity": "critical",
            "isDirect": false,
            "via": [
                {
                    "source": 1094446,
                    "name": "@babel/traverse",
                    "dependency": "@babel/traverse",
                    "title": "Babel vulnerable to arbitrary code execution when compiling specifically crafted malicious code",
                    "url": "https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-67hx-6x53-jw92",
                    "severity": "critical",
                    "cwe": [
                        "CWE-184",
                        "CWE-697"
                    ],
                    "cvss": {
                        "score": 9.3,
                        "vectorString": "CVSS:3.1/AV:L/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:C/C:H/I:H/A:H"
                    },
                    "range": "<7.23.2"
                }
            ],
            "effects": [],
            "range": "<7.23.2",
            "nodes": [
                "node_modules/@babel/traverse"
            ],
            "fixAvailable": true
        }
    }
}
$reportJson = @();
foreach($object_properties in $data.vulnerabilities.PSObject.Properties){
    $reportJson += @{
        name = $object_properties.Value.name;
        severity = $object_properties.Value.severity;
        Fixedin= $object_properties.Value.range;
        fixAvailable= $object_properties.Value.fixAvailable;
        cwe= $object_properties.Value.via.cwe;
        cvss=$object_properties.Value.via.cvss;
    };
}
$reportJson | ConvertTo-Json > audit-report.json
$data2 = Get-Content -Raw audit-report.json  | ConvertFrom-Json;
$data2 | Export-Csv -Path audit-report.csv -NoTypeInformation  -Encoding UTF8
```

This creates the file audit-report.json and auidt-report.csv:

```
[
    {
        "name":  "@babel/traverse",
        "fixAvailable":  true,
        "cvss":  {
                     "score":  9.3,
                     "vectorString":  "CVSS:3.1/AV:L/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:C/C:H/I:H/A:H"
                 },
        "cwe":  [
                    "CWE-184",
                    "CWE-697"
                ],
        "severity":  "critical",
        "fixedin":  "\u003c7.23.2"
    },
```

but the csv doesnt fetch the "CWE-184","CWE-697" values and prints System.Object[]
csv  file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIB3t.png)

"@babel/traverse","True","@{score=9.3; vectorString=CVSS:3.1/AV:L/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:C/C:H/I:H/A:H}","System.Object[]","critical","<7.23.2"

it should print the array values.

"@babel/traverse","True","@{score=9.3; vectorString=CVSS:3.1/AV:L/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:C/C:H/I:H/A:H}","CWE-184","CWE-697","critical","<7.23.2"

Thanks...please help

it should get "CWE-184","CWE-697" values instead of system.object[]

Comment: `$reportJson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10`. As an aside: [try avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026) as it is inefficiënt.

Comment: Unfortunately the default depth is 2.  In powershell 7 it gives a warning.